# Google Line Chart convert timeofday to number

Tags: javascript, php, json, charts, google-visualization

I work on a line chart but have the problem that the format of this line can not be changed:

`function drawChart(){
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('timeofday','quartal');`

I want in the horizontal axis a simple number format (1,2,3,4 as quarters) but when i changed it to 'number' the chart disappears.

Second problem is here that the chart shows by hovering the lines 'NaN:NaN'. I think this is caused by the wrong format too.

JSON Format is this: 4[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff9Dn.png),0,1], [[2],1,1], [[3],1,1], [[4],2,8]

Can not understand why the [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff9Dn.png),[2],[3],[4] from above can not be a number.

This is my actual chart:

[image: Chart]

I have following code:

```
<?php 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$qry = "SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN name_Gleitzeitrahmen = 'Ja' THEN 1 END) as Ja,COUNT(CASE WHEN name_Gleitzeitrahmen = 'Nein' THEN 1 END)as Nein,quarter(datum) as quartal FROM dashboard GROUP BY quartal";
$result = $conn->query($qry);

if($result === FALSE) {
echo mysqli_errno($result) .": ". mysqli_error($result) ."/n";
die(mysqli_error());
}
$i = 0; //iteration counter - start at 0

$totalRows = mysqli_num_rows($result); // we need this to know when to change the output
$targetRows = $totalRows - 1; //row indies start from 0, not 1.

foreach ($result as $row){ 

  //$comTime = str_replace(":",",",$row['quartal']); // for each row, remove the : and put , in its place -> nur wenn Zeitformat vorhanden
    $comTime = $row['quartal'];
    if ($targetRows == $i) { // if the index is the same value as the target (ie, it's the last row)...

        $temp = "[[".$comTime."],".($row['Ja']).",".($row['Nein'])."]". PHP_EOL;
        } else {
        $temp = "[[".$comTime."],".($row['Ja']).",".($row['Nein'])."],". PHP_EOL;
        }
    $i = $i + 1; 
    $rows[] = $temp; 
}

$table = $rows;
$data = implode($table); //format the table as a single string, with line returns

echo $i;
echo $data;

?>



<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart(){
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('timeofday','quartal'); //
        data.addColumn('number','Ja'); //Typ number
        data.addColumn('number','Nein');
        data.addRows([              
            <?php echo $data; ?> //dump the result into here, as it's correctly formatted   
        ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Recorded Temperatures',
        legend: { position: 'top' },
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        hAxis: { format:'hh:mm:ss'},
        hAxis: { gridlines: { count: 4 } }

    }; 

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);    
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see --> [working with timeofday](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#working-with-timeofday)

> The DataTable `'timeofday'` column data type takes an array of either 3 or 4 numbers, representing hours, minutes, seconds, and optionally milliseconds, respectively.

which means the value for `'timeofday'` must be an array with at least 3 values...

the data would need to look something like this...

```
[[1,0,0],1,1], [[2,0,0],1,1], [[3,0,0],1,1], [[4,0,0],2,8]
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('timeofday','quartal');
  data.addColumn('number','Ja');
  data.addColumn('number','Nein');
  data.addRows([
    [[1,0,0],1,1], [[2,0,0],1,1], [[3,0,0],1,1], [[4,0,0],2,8]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**EDIT**

according to the [data-format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#data-format) for a line chart,
the x-axis can be of any valid column type available

changing to a `'number'`...

```
data.addColumn('number','quartal');
```

would mean removing the inner array for the first column of data...

```
[1,1,1], [2,1,1], [3,1,1], [4,2,8]
```

the php would need to change to something like...

```
if ($targetRows == $i) {
  $temp = "[".$comTime.",".($row['Ja']).",".($row['Nein'])."]". PHP_EOL;
} else {
  $temp = "[".$comTime.",".($row['Ja']).",".($row['Nein'])."],". PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply but I do not want timeofday format, i want only a number but only timeofday works with this chart at the moment.
Need help to find out how to change the code to get only the numbers 1,2,3,4 on the x- axis.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what i want!